# How to select congruent polygons in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, polygon, select

Title says it all. What is the best way to select congruent polygons in PostGIS?

```
CREATE TABLE polygon_a (
gid serial NOT NULL,
geom geometry(Polygon, your_SRID),
CONSTRAINT polygon_a_pkey PRIMARY KEY (gid)
);

CREATE TABLE polygon_b (
gid serial NOT NULL,
geom geometry(Polygon, your_SRID),
CONSTRAINT polygon_b_pkey PRIMARY KEY (gid)
);
```

[image]

```
SELECT * FROM polygon_b
WHERE
-- ???
;
```

Comment: Please **edit** the question to use words to describe what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you probably mean is how to find polygons that are 'spatially equal'. What you need then is WHERE ST_Equals(geoma, geomb). Read the docs: http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Equals.html